# CRM 2013 Plugin: Setting up new relationship on newly created Accounts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, plugins, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm creating a plugin for CRM 2013 (on-premise). My requirement is like this:

1. When a custom entity "Contract" creates, fire the plugin.
2. Contract has "1:1" relationship with the Quote entity.
3. Quote has a 1:N relationship with custom entity 'Property'.
4. For every properties that Quote has, create new Account records.
5. **Link the newly created Account records to the Contract. The relationship Contract to Account is 1 to N.**

I got all working however keep getting problems with #5. For some reason the plugin throws an error that Account ID does not exist.

Here's my code:

```
foreach ("**Property records found in Quote**")
                {

                    var accountEntity = new Entity();
                    accountEntity = new Entity("account");
                    if (record.Attributes.Contains("name"))
                    {
                        accountEntity["name"] = record.Attributes["propertyname"];
                    }
                    else throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, "New Property Name is needed.");

                    service.Create(accountEntity);

                    var referenceCollection = new EntityReferenceCollection();
                    var relatedEntity = new EntityReference
                    {
                        Id = record.Id,
                        LogicalName = record.LogicalName
                    };
                    referenceCollection.Add(relatedEntity);
                    //The relationship schema name in CRM you are using to associate the entities. 
                    var relRelationship = new Relationship
                    {
                        SchemaName = "new_new_contract_account"
                    };

                    service.Associate("account", ContractId, relRelationship, referenceCollection);

                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store the **id** of the newly created account:

```
var accountid = service.Create(accountEntity);
```

**relatedEntity** object must be set with the following properties:

```
var relatedEntity = new EntityReference
{
   Id =  accountid, /*the newly created account's id*/
   LogicalName = "account"
};
```

replace your **service.Associate** line with:

```
service.Associate("new_contract", ContractId, relRelationship, referenceCollection);
```

Comment: Note: you can make this efficient by combining all the created accounts in the referenceCollection object.